# Pandas - How can I find a value across multiple columns based on a pattern and add it to a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dynamic, multiple-columns

Dataframe:

```
C1   C2   C3
------------
A1  NaN  NaN
NaN NaN   A0
NaN  A2  NaN
```

Desired Result:

```
C1   C2   C3   MATCH
--------------------
A1  NaN  NaN      A1  
NaN NaN   A0      A0
NaN  A2  NaN      A2
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
df['MATCHED'] = df[<dynamic based on value '^A\d{1}$' found in ANY column>]
```

What I'm currently doing:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def m(r):
    for x in r.values:
        if re.findall('^A\d{1}$', str(x)):
            return x
    return None

df = pd.DataFrame([{'C1': 'A1'}, {'C2': 'A2'}, {'C3': 'A0'}])
df['MATCHED'] = [m(row) for i, row in df.iterrows()]
```

My current approach works, but it seems like I'm missing something and there is a more elegant/efficient way to do this.

Comment: what if a row contains 2 valid values like `A1  NaN  A2` ? How would it choose?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```py
df['MATCHED'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[row.str.fullmatch('^A\d{1}$').replace(np.nan, False).tolist()].iloc[0], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    C1   C2   C3 MATCHED
0   A1  NaN  NaN      A1
1  NaN   A2  NaN      A2
2  NaN  NaN   A0      A0
```

Explanation:

- Use `apply()` to iterate over the input rows
- Use `str.fullmatch()` on the row to get a row of booleans (or NaN values) indicating match
- Use `replace()` to change NaN values to False
- Use `tolist()` to convert the Series to a boolean mask
- Use the mask to get the matching value(s) from the row
- Use `iloc[0]` to pull out the first matching value
- Put these matching values in the new column `MATCHED`.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) the potential multiple matches (as `A1,A2,A3`):

```
df['MATCH'] = (df.stack().str.extract('^(A\d+)$', expand=False)
                 .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
              )
```

*NB. if you only want the first match use `.first()` in place of `.agg(','.join)`.*

If you are sure that there is only **one** match per row:

```
df['MATCH'] = (df.stack().str.extract('^(A\d+)$', expand=False)
                 .dropna().droplevel(1)
              )
```

Output:

```
    C1   C2   C3 MATCH
0   A1  NaN  NaN    A1
1  NaN  NaN   A0    A0
2  NaN   A2  NaN    A2
```